# OpenGL - Plotting Points from external file

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, freeglut, opengl-compat

AM trying to plot some points from a CSV file. Since the file size is large(>2GB), loading the file contents to the vector `std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >parsedCsv` threw an out of memory exception.

So I thought, instead of reading the file to a vector and then plotting it, Is is possible to plot it directly from the CSV. Am looking for some modification below on `glVertex3f(x,y,z)`

```
    std::ifstream  data("D:\\Files\\Dummy2.csv");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(data, line))
    {
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);
        std::string cell;
        std::vector<std::string> parsedRow;
        while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, ','))
        {
            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(----how to represent the points--?)
            glEnd();
        }
```

The CSV file is already of desired format :

```
x1,y1,z1    
x2,y2,z2    
x3,y3,z3    
-------
----
--
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Small note: this way of working requires one read-through of the entire file per rendered frame. If you intend to add zooming/panning/ANYTHING to the program you will either need to re-read the file or upload the points to the GPU with a VBO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/) to convert the string values to floating point numbers. Push the numbers of the cells to the [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/). The components of the vertex vertex coordinate are stored in the `vector` and can be be drawn by [`glVertex3fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml):

```cpp
std::ifstream data("D:\\Files\\Dummy2.csv");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(data, line))
{
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);

    std::string cell;
    std::vector<float> parsedRow;
    while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, ','))
        parsedRow.push_back(std::stof(cell));

    if (parsedRow.size() == 3)
    {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3fv(parsedRow.data());
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

Note, if `stof` can not performed a conversion, then an invalid argument exception is thrown.

Comment: Will the entire data be stored in the vector ?. because I have been using the same method but only for smaller sized data.

Comment: @Sid133 No, the vector just contains 1 point (the data of 1 line). When the next line is read, then the data of the previous line is lost. Note `parsedRow` is a local variable in the block scope of the outer loop.

Comment: For 1.7Mb file of 57600 points its taking about 8 sec to load.OpenGL rendering is taking only one sec, but reading from external csv file is slow . Is there a more faster way to read the files ?

Comment: @Sid133 Why do you not read the content of a file to a buffer and  draw the files from the buffer? 57600 vertices are not very many.

Comment: I got that. But the slowness am experiencing is with the reading only. Is reading to a buffer faster than reading to a vector ?. And is it possible to read external files directly to a buffer instead of using a vector in between as in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44687218/9304804. However i was able to increase the speed little bit more after using fscanf rather than getline `if (FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r"))
 {
  while (fscanf(fp, "%f,%f,%f", &x, &y, &z) == 3)`