# glVertex3fv giving error in when i read a data using ifstream in OpenGL C++

Tags: c++

I am making an OpenGL program using C++ on Visual Studio. I have read the CSV file data for the coordinates using a code available on Stackoverflow [OpenGL - Plotting Points from external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410498/opengl-plotting-points-from-external-file). But now I am getting errors on the object with ifstream. You can consult the link to get a better understanding ([OpenGL - Plotting Points from external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410498/opengl-plotting-points-from-external-file)).

```
// CSV File Loader and 3D Rendering Class

#include "CSV.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "C:\Users\srcco\Desktop\Track Viewer\glut-3.7\include\GL\glut.h"
using namespace std;
CSV::CSV(string Fname) {
    class CSV {
    public:
        CSV() {
            ifstream csvdata("demo.csv");
            string line;
            while (getline(csvdata,line))
            {
                stringstream lineStream(line);
                string cell;
                vector<float> parsedRow;
                while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, ','))
                {
                    parsedRow.push_back(stof(cell));
                }
                if (parsedRow.size() == 3)
                {
                    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                    glVertex3fv(parsedRow.csvdata());
                    glEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I am getting error in `glVertex3fv(parsedRow.csvdata());`
Error is `E0135 class "std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>" has no member "csvdata"   Main`

Answer (score 0):

There is non member `csvdata()`.

I guess you want `data()` instead?